Is there any reason to still use GPT 3.5?
I read on https://openai.com/api/pricing/:

GPT-4o mini is our most cost-efficient small model that’s smarter and cheaper than GPT-3.5 Turbo, and has vision capabilities. The model has 128K context and an October 2023 knowledge cutoff.

Is there any reason to still use GPT 3.5?

gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct is the only model that still has the suffix parameter in the API. I use it in many hypothesis-generating applications.

I'm speculating here:
Unlike many more recent models, a GPT-3.5 variant is still available as an instruction model, without chat-conversation and online-search capabilities.

gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct:   Similar capabilities as GPT-3 era models. Compatible with legacy Completions endpoint and not Chat Completions.

I have noticed that some third-party libraries, e.g., some functions in older versions of Langchain-python 0.1.x, call those l"egacy Completions Endpoint"s.  These methods may send hyperparameters that 4o- models/endpoints do not accept, rejecting the request.
So I think backward compatibility with established developer base, and with legacy Apps relying on the API, is one reason they keep it available in the Web Interface (for convenience).

As of July 2024, gpt-4o-mini should be used in place of gpt-3.5-turbo, as it is cheaper, more capable, multimodal, and just as fast. gpt-3.5-turbo is still available for use in the API.

(from same page).
Update: If you happen to use these endpoints via API, OpenAI will send a notice like this:
In June 2023 and November 2023, we announced the deprecation of the following models, with a planned shutdown date of September 13th, 2024:

     gpt-3.5-turbo-0301 
     gpt-3.5-turbo-0613
     gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613

We have noticed that your organization has recently used at least one of these models. As soon as possible, we encourage you to migrate to gpt-4o-mini, our new small model that will give you higher performance at lower cost.

Thanks for building with OpenAI. If you have any questions about model migration, feel free to reach out on the OpenAI Developer Forum.


Naively seen, 4o-mini scores higher and is cheaper. A caveeat might be in how representative are the benchmarks, and if with interations the models start overfitting to these benchmarks somewhat. I've heard people being actually quite dissatisfied with 4o-mini in complex reasoning and non-english language, more than I would expect given high ranking of 4o-mini on llm arena.
Some people will keep using turbo because their prompts or other parts of the system might be optimized and working well with 3.5-turbo.
